# How to create new folder in Eclipse Helios CDT with symbolic link?

Tags: eclipse, symlink, eclipse-cdt, helios

I have just upgraded my Eclipse CDT from Galileo to Helios and it seems that I can't create a new folder in my C++ project that links to a symbolic link on the filesystem.  I need this because our nightly build system keeps a history of builds and updates a symbolic link to point to the latest source.  It looks something like this:

```
/project/monday
/project/tuesday
/project/wednesday
/project/thursday
/project/friday
/project/lastnight -> /project/tuesday
```

With Galileo I could create the folder with the "Link to Folder in File System" that was "/project/lastnight".  When I got to work in the morning I would just select the folder and hit refresh and the indexes would be updated.  I could then use this reference this project from my other projects.

Is this possible with Helios?  Or is there some other way I should be doing this?

Regards,
Mike

EDIT: I am running eclipse on linux.

Answer (score 8):

Resource view -> Create new folders -> Advanced -> Link to...

Comment: This won't allow me to link to a file that is not a folder " Path target is of wrong type.  The path must point to a folder."

Answer (score 1):

From the Eclipse Help..

1. In one of the navigation views, right-click the project or folder where you want to create the linked folder.
2. From the pop-up menu, select  command link New > Folder.
3. Specify the name of the folder as it will appear in the workbench. This name can be different from the name of the folder in the file system.
4. Click Advanced.
5. Check Link to alternate location (Linked Folder).
6. Enter a file system path, or click Browse to select a folder in the file system.
7. Click Finish.

Answer (score 0):

you can find it in preferences: General->Workspace->Linked resources.
you can drag the folder into eclipse (at least in windows, not sure about linux) and the it will ask you whethear to link it or copy.
if not, Do it from the command line and then refresh the eclipse project.

```
cd ../project
ln -s tuesday lastnight
```

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't get the directory into a project.  Is there a step missing?

Comment: try the command line solution. I tried it and it works for me. If it is not working you probably need to give more details about the problem.